# How to code an arrow using css

Tags: css, css-shapes, arrows

Hi guys I'm trying to code an arrow like this in css, I'e viewed examples on codepen, but now I'm thinking whether it is actually possible?

[image: arrows]

Comment: Try CSS triangle for arrows.

Comment: It is possible, but you'll end up using CSS in a way you probably should not. At least not in real-world projects. In an SVG you could do this kind of thing using more concise and understandable code with an overall better and more flexible result.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For arrow and lines i have use `border`

```css
.content {
  margin-top: 30px;
  position: relative;
  border: 2px solid black;
  border-bottom: 2px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 40px;
}

.content:before,
.content:after,
.center:before {
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  border-width: 8px 8px;
  border-color: #000 transparent transparent transparent;
  border-style: solid;
  position: absolute;
}

.content:before {
  left: -8px;
  top: 36px;
}

.content:after {
  right: -8px;
  top: 36px;
}

.center:before {
  right: -8px;
  top: 60px;
}

.center {
  position: absolute;
  height: 60px;
  top: -24px;
  left: 50%;
  margin-left:-2px;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div class="center">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 5):

Here is another trick using only one element and multiple linear-gradient as background and you can adjust the size/position of each arrow individually:

```css
.arrows {
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
  background:
  /* For the 3 lines*/
  linear-gradient(#000,#000) 10px 25px/2px calc(100% - 30px),
  linear-gradient(#000,#000) 50% 0/2px calc(100% - 2px),
  linear-gradient(#000,#000) calc(100% - 10px) 25px/2px calc(100% - 30px),
  /*for the arrows*/
  linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 50%,#000 0%) 10px 100%/10px 10px,
  linear-gradient(to top right,transparent 50%,#000 0%) 0px 100%/10px 10px,
  
  linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 50%,#000 0%) calc(50% + 5px) 100%/10px 10px,
  linear-gradient(to top right,transparent 50%,#000 0%) calc(50% - 5px) 100%/10px 10px,
  
  linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 50%,#000 0%) 100% 100%/10px 10px,
  linear-gradient(to top right,transparent 50%,#000 0%) calc(100% - 10px) 100%/10px 10px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.arrows:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:10px;
  right:10px;
  height:8px;
  border:2px solid;
  border-bottom:none;
  border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrows"></div>
```

**How does each arrow work?**

For each element we have the **line** and the **extremity**:

1. For the line, we simply need a `linear-gradient` with a solid color then we adjust the `backround-size` to control the line:

So if I consider this linear gradient:

```css
body {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin:0;
  background: linear-gradient(#000,#000) 10px 25px/2px calc(100% - 30px) no-repeat;
}
```

We can read it as follow : Draw a line from `10px,25px` with a thickness of 2px and a length of `100%` minus `30px`. `100%` will refer to the height of the container.

2. For the extremity we will need **two** gradients, each one will create a rectangle triangle. To do this I simply need to specify a diagonal direction to my gradient (for example: `to top right`):

So if I consider this linear gradient:

```css
body {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin:0;
  background: linear-gradient(to top right, #000 50%, transparent 0%) 30px 30px/10px 10px no-repeat;
}
```

We can read it as follow: start my gradient from `30px,30px` with a size of `10px * 10px` and fill `50%` of it with black following the **top right** direction. So we will end up with a rectangle triangle having left and bottom side equal to `10px`.

We do the same to create the other extremity and we simply make them close to each other to create the final visual:

```css
body {
  height: 200px;
  border: 1px solid;
  margin:0;
  background: 
   linear-gradient(to top right, #000 50%, transparent 0%) 30px 30px/10px 10px no-repeat,
   linear-gradient(to top left,  #000 50%, transparent 0%) 20px 30px/10px 10px no-repeat;
}
```

Now all you have to do is to combine all these linear gradient and adjust size/position to obtain your layout.

You can easily scale for more arrows if needed as you simply need to append more gradient:

```css
.arrows {
  width:300px;
  height:100px;
  position:relative;
  background:
  /* For the lines*/
  linear-gradient(#000,#000) 10px 25px/2px calc(100% - 50px),
  linear-gradient(#000,#000) 19% 20px/2px calc(100% - 30px),
  linear-gradient(#000,#000) 50% 0/2px calc(100% - 2px),
  linear-gradient(#000,#000) 70% 20px/2px calc(100% - 80px),
  linear-gradient(#000,#000) calc(100% - 10px) 25px/2px calc(100% - 30px),
  linear-gradient(#000,#000) calc(50% + 20px) 60px/ 40px 2px,
  /*for the arrows*/
  linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 50%,#000 0%) 10px calc(100% - 20px)/10px 10px,
  linear-gradient(to top right,transparent 50%,#000 0%) 0px calc(100% - 20px)/10px 10px,
  
  linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 50%,#000 0%) 20% calc(100% - 8px)/10px 10px,
  linear-gradient(to top right,transparent 50%,#000 0%) calc(20% - 10px) calc(100% - 8px)/10px 10px,
  
  linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 50%,#000 0%) calc(50% + 5px) 100%/10px 10px,
  linear-gradient(to top right,transparent 50%,#000 0%) calc(50% - 5px) 100%/10px 10px,
  
  linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 50%,#000 0%) 72% calc(100% - 58px)/10px 10px,
  linear-gradient(to top right,transparent 50%,#000 0%) calc(72% - 10px) calc(100% - 58px)/10px 10px,
  
  linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 50%,#000 0%) 100% 100%/10px 10px,
  linear-gradient(to top right,transparent 50%,#000 0%) calc(100% - 10px) 100%/10px 10px,
  
  linear-gradient(to top left,transparent 50%,#000 0%) calc(50% + 42px) 62px/10px 10px,
  linear-gradient(to bottom left,transparent 50%,#000 0%) calc(50% + 42px) 52px/10px 10px;
 background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.arrows:before {
  content:"";
  position:absolute;
  top:20px;
  left:10px;
  right:10px;
  height:8px;
  border:2px solid;
  border-bottom:none;
  border-radius:10px 10px 0 0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="arrows"></div>
```

Comment: wow that's amazing, may I ask if I were to resize the browser I would use @media, what variable should I edit ?

Comment: @GoodJeans yes sure :) .. for each gradient you have you something like this [ a b/c d ] .. a & b control the postion of the gradient like an x/y value, so you specifiy from where the gradient will start. The c & d values control the size of the gradient so you tell how big is the gradient, with this i control the size of each line and each arrow. What i advice you is to use only one arrow and play by changing the values and see what happen so you understand how to modify each value ;)

Comment: @GoodJeans by the why you ca as i did use % value and only resize the box and thus the gradient will follow this resize

Comment: @GoodJeans i edited my answer with a detailed explanation :)

Answer (score 0):

An arrow in itself is created from an equilateral block of 0 height and width (with only the borders making up the visible element). And then you only show the left border to have a right arrow, the right border for the left arrow and so on and so forth.

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/css-triangle/

As far as adding the lines it's a matter of 0 height block elements and the required width for size of horizontal lines and 0 width and the required height for vertical lines.

I went ahead and created the following CSS

```
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>CSS Arrows</title>
            <style type="text/css">
                .arrow {
                    margin: 5px;
                }

                .arrow_sm {
                    border: 5px solid transparent;
                }

                .arrow_sm p {
                    font-size: 10px;
                    margin-top: -6px;
                }

                .arrow_md {
                    border: 10px solid transparent;
                }

                .arrow_md p {
                    font-size: 20px;
                    margin-top: -12px;
                }

                .arrow_lg {
                    border: 15px solid transparent;
                }

                .arrow_lg p {
                    font-size: 30px;
                    margin-top: -18px;
                }

                .arrow_right {
                    height: 0;
                    border-left-color: blue; 
                }

                .arrow_right {
                    padding-left: 2px;
                }

                .arrow_down {
                    width: 0;
                    border-top-color: red; 
                }

                .arrow_down p {
                    padding-top: 2px;
                    padding-bottom: 2px;
                    transform: rotate(90deg);
                    transform-origin: middle top 0;
                }

                .arrow_left {
                    height: 0;
                    text-align: right;
                    border-right-color: green; 
                }

                .arrow_left p {
                    text-align: right;
                    padding-right: 2px;
                }

                .arrow_up {
                    width: 0;
                    border-bottom-color: black; 
                }

                .arrow_up p {
                    margin: 0 0 -.4em -.2em;
                    transform: rotate(-90deg);
                    transform-origin: middle bottom 0;
                }

                .vertical_line {
                    width: 2px;
                }

                .horizontal_line {
                    height: 2px;
                }

                .line_v_sm {
                    height: 30px;
                    border-left: 2px solid green;
                }

                .line_v_md {
                    height: 45px;
                    border-left: 2px solid red;
                }

                .line_v_lg {
                    height: 60px;
                    border-left: 2px solid black;
                }

                .line_h_sm {
                    width: 30px;
                    border-top: 2px solid green;
                }

                .line_h_md {
                    width: 45px;
                    border-top: 2px solid red;
                }

                .line_h_lg {
                    width: 60px;
                    border-top: 2px solid black;
                }

                .inline {
                    display: inline-block;
                }

                .vertical_stem_sm {
                    margin-top: -.5em;
                    margin-left: .6em;
                    margin-bottom: -.5em;
                }

                .vertical_stem_md {
                    margin-top: -.8em;
                    margin-left: .9em;
                    margin-bottom: -.8em;
                }

                .vertical_stem_lg {
                    margin-top: -1.1em;
                    margin-left: 1.2em;
                    margin-bottom: -1.1em;
                }

                .horizontal_stem_sm {
                    margin-left: -.6em;
                    margin-right: -.6em;
                }

                .horizontal_stem_md {
                    margin-top: -7px;
                    margin-left: -.6em;
                    margin-right: -.6em;
                }

                .horizontal_stem_lg {
                    margin-top: -12px;
                    margin-left: -.6em;
                    margin-right: -.6em;
                }
            </style>
        </head>
        <body>
            <!-- arrow arrow_size arrow_direction //-->
            <div class="arrow arrow_sm arrow_right"><p>Right</p></div>
            <div class="arrow arrow_md arrow_right"><p>Right</p></div>
            <div class="arrow arrow_lg arrow_right"><p>Right</p></div>

            <div class="arrow arrow_sm arrow_down"><p>Down</p></div>
            <div class="arrow arrow_md arrow_down"><p>Down</p></div>
            <div class="arrow arrow_lg arrow_down"><p>Down</p></div>

            <div class="arrow arrow_sm arrow_left"><p>Left</p></div>
            <div class="arrow arrow_md arrow_left"><p>Left</p></div>
            <div class="arrow arrow_lg arrow_left"><p>Left</p></div>

            <div class="arrow arrow_sm arrow_up"><p>Up</p></div>
            <div class="arrow arrow_md arrow_up"><p>Up</p></div>
            <div class="arrow arrow_lg arrow_up"><p>Up</p></div>


            <div class="arrow arrow_sm arrow_right"></div>
            <div class="arrow arrow_md arrow_right"></div>
            <div class="arrow arrow_lg arrow_right"></div>

            <div class="arrow arrow_sm arrow_down"></div>
            <div class="arrow arrow_md arrow_down"></div>
            <div class="arrow arrow_lg arrow_down"></div>

            <div class="arrow arrow_sm arrow_left"></div>
            <div class="arrow arrow_md arrow_left"></div>
            <div class="arrow arrow_lg arrow_left"></div>

            <div class="arrow arrow_sm arrow_up"></div>
            <div class="arrow arrow_md arrow_up"></div>
            <div class="arrow arrow_lg arrow_up"></div>

            <div class="vertical_line line_v_sm"></div>
            <div class="vertical_line line_v_md"></div>
            <div class="vertical_line line_v_lg"></div>

            <div class="horizontal_line line_h_sm"></div>
            <div class="horizontal_line line_h_md"></div>
            <div class="horizontal_line line_h_lg"></div>

            <!-- Small arrow and stem for small arrow //-->
            <div style="margin-left: 70px;">
                <div class="arrow arrow_sm arrow_up"><p>Up</p></div>
                <div class="vertical_line line_v_lg vertical_stem_sm"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="arrow arrow_sm arrow_left inline"><p>Left</p></div>
            <div class="horizontal_line line_h_lg inline horizontal_stem_sm"></div>

            <div class="horizontal_line line_h_lg inline horizontal_stem_sm"></div>
            <div class="arrow arrow_sm arrow_right inline"><p>Right</p></div>
            <div style="margin-left: 70px;">
                <div class="vertical_line line_v_lg vertical_stem_sm"></div>
                <div class="arrow arrow_sm arrow_down"><p>Down</p></div>
            </div>

            <!-- Medium arrow and stem for medium arrow //-->
            <div style="margin-left: 90px;">
                <div class="arrow arrow_md arrow_up"><p>Up</p></div>
                <div class="vertical_line line_v_lg vertical_stem_md"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="arrow arrow_md arrow_left inline"><p>Left</p></div>
            <div class="horizontal_line line_h_lg inline horizontal_stem_md"></div>

            <div class="horizontal_line line_h_lg inline horizontal_stem_md"></div>
            <div class="arrow arrow_md arrow_right inline"><p>Right</p></div>
            <div style="margin-left: 90px;">
                <div class="vertical_line line_v_lg vertical_stem_md"></div>
                <div class="arrow arrow_md arrow_down"><p>Down</p></div>
            </div>

            <!-- Large arrow and stem for large arrow //-->
            <div style="margin-left: 120px;">
                <div class="arrow arrow_lg arrow_up"><p>Up</p></div>
                <div class="vertical_line line_v_lg vertical_stem_lg"></div>
            </div>

            <div class="arrow arrow_lg arrow_left inline"><p>Left</p></div>
            <div class="horizontal_line line_h_lg inline horizontal_stem_lg"></div>

            <div class="horizontal_line line_h_lg inline horizontal_stem_lg"></div>
            <div class="arrow arrow_lg arrow_right inline"><p>Right</p></div>
            <div style="margin-left: 120px;">
                <div class="vertical_line line_v_lg vertical_stem_lg"></div>
                <div class="arrow arrow_lg arrow_down"><p>Down</p></div>
            </div>
        </body>
    </html>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/2ykpwwgt/1/

For some reason in JSFiddle it doesn't parse like it does in my browser.

Well, you got an idea and something to play with with one method