# How do I break a line if I'm working with css?

Tags: css

[image]

Try to create arrows and lines like images.

Is that possible with CSS alone?

Could it be better to draw with SVG?

Comment: please show us some effort you've put in this, add some code to your question... (anyway it is possible with css transformations)

Comment: check this : https://stackoverflow.com/a/48606321/8620333 a CSS only solution

Comment: @Pete I don't think that is what soria was after.

Comment: @James I didn't guess answer, I gave a comment with a useful tool for generating an arrow head - and if you actually read my previous comment, my works firewall blocks images on imgur so reposting the link really doesn't help

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are a lot of ways to achieve this, here is one.

```css
#funky-arrow {
  border-top: 1px solid #000;
  text-align: right;
  max-width: 210px;
}

#funky-arrow > div {
  border-bottom: 5px solid transparent;
  border-right: 5px solid #000;
  border-top: 5px solid transparent;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 0;
  position: relative;
  right: -6px;
  top: 18px;
  width: 0;
}

#funky-arrow:after {
  background-color: #000;
  content: "";
  display: inline-block;
  height: 1px;
  transform: rotate(-20deg);
  width: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div id="funky-arrow">
  <div></div>
</div>
```